# User cron jobs are not being executed any more (perhaps SELinux)

Tags: fedora, cron, selinux

I have the following output as a user running `crontab -l`:

```
#Ansible: backup-external chaos
*/20 * * * * flock --nonblock /home/mu/.cache/backup-external.lock backup-external chaos
*/20 * * * * /home/mu/bin/ddc-save-brightness
```

Neither job is executed. If I run them manually, they seem to work just fine.

The `Ansible` snippet there comes from using Ansible to add this one job for my user.

Looking at `systemctl status crond.service -l` makes it clear that the service itself is running. It seems to fail to load the crontab for my user `mu` due to SELinux it seems:

```
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mi 2016-01-27 17:51:08 CET; 1h 43min ago
 Main PID: 1351 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─1351 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Jan 27 17:51:09 martin-friese.fritz.box crond[1351]: (mu) Unauthorized SELinux context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 file_context=unconfined_u:object_r:user_cron_spool_t:s0 (/var/spool/cron/mu)
Jan 27 17:51:09 martin-friese.fritz.box crond[1351]: (mu) FAILED (loading cron table)
Jan 27 17:51:09 martin-friese.fritz.box crond[1351]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jan 27 18:01:01 martin-friese.fritz.box CROND[3726]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 27 18:01:01 martin-friese.fritz.box anacron[3737]: Anacron started on 2016-01-27
Jan 27 18:01:01 martin-friese.fritz.box anacron[3737]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 13 min.
Jan 27 18:01:01 martin-friese.fritz.box anacron[3737]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jan 27 18:01:01 martin-friese.fritz.box run-parts[3741]: (/etc/cron.hourly) starting mcelog.cron
Jan 27 18:14:01 martin-friese.fritz.box anacron[3737]: Job `cron.daily' started
Jan 27 19:01:01 martin-friese.fritz.box CROND[2681]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

This is on Fedora 23 and I did not change the SELinux policy, so it is probably enforcing strictly.

What do I have to change in order to get the jobs running again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was resolved in this bugzilla: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1298192

Please make sure you have the latest kernel: `4.3.3-301`

Comment: Interesting! I am now running `4.3.3-303.fc23.x86_64` and my jobs are working again without changing anything.